# JSON to Datagridview is not working in my case c#

Tags: c#, json, datagridview, json.net

I have one JSON after calling an API. I have tried many methods to extract data from JSON and then bind it to datagridview but fails everytime. So i want someone to help me with it.
I have a JSON class got from http://json2csharp.com

```
public class Attributes
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string finerCateg { get; set; }
    public string mainimageurl { get; set; }
    public string productTaxCode { get; set; }
    public string productUrlText { get; set; }
    public string caResidentsPropWarningRequired { get; set; }
    public string prodClassType { get; set; }
    public string canonicalUrl { get; set; }
    public string compositeWood { get; set; }
    public string numOfBatt { get; set; }
    public string actualColor { get; set; }
    public string multipackQuantity { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public string ironBankCategory { get; set; }
    public string isSortable { get; set; }
    public string replenishmentEndDate { get; set; }
    public string features { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string simsInventoryType { get; set; }
    public string isPvtLabelUnbranded { get; set; }
    public string fuelRestriction { get; set; }
    public string hasWarranty { get; set; }
}

public class BestMarketplacePrice
{
    public double price { get; set; }
    public string sellerInfo { get; set; }
    public double standardShipRate { get; set; }
    public double twoThreeDayShippingRate { get; set; }
    public bool availableOnline { get; set; }
    public bool clearance { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int itemId { get; set; }
    public int parentItemId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double msrp { get; set; }
    public double salePrice { get; set; }
    public string upc { get; set; }
    public string categoryPath { get; set; }
    public string shortDescription { get; set; }
    public string longDescription { get; set; }
    public string brandName { get; set; }
    public string thumbnailImage { get; set; }
    public string mediumImage { get; set; }
    public string largeImage { get; set; }
    public string productTrackingUrl { get; set; }
    public double standardShipRate { get; set; }
    public double twoThreeDayShippingRate { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public bool marketplace { get; set; }
    public string modelNumber { get; set; }
    public string sellerInfo { get; set; }
    public string productUrl { get; set; }
    public string customerRating { get; set; }
    public int numReviews { get; set; }
    public string customerRatingImage { get; set; }
    public string categoryNode { get; set; }
    public string rhid { get; set; }
    public bool bundle { get; set; }
    public bool clearance { get; set; }
    public bool preOrder { get; set; }
    public string stock { get; set; }
    public Attributes attributes { get; set; }
    public string addToCartUrl { get; set; }
    public string affiliateAddToCartUrl { get; set; }
    public bool freeShippingOver35Dollars { get; set; }
    public bool availableOnline { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public bool? ninetySevenCentShipping { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public bool? shipToStore { get; set; }
    public bool? freeShipToStore { get; set; }
    public BestMarketplacePrice bestMarketplacePrice { get; set; }
    public List<int?> variants { get; set; }
    public bool? freight { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string brand { get; set; }
    public string format { get; set; }
    public string nextPage { get; set; }
    public string totalPages { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

Decerialization code is:

```
 List<RootObject> stores = new List<RootObject>();
RootObject ScrapedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Test\Data1.json"));
stores.Add(ScrapedResult);
dataGridViewScrapedData.DataSource = stores;
```

> Other than that i have also checked API is returning result successfully in the
>   string which is "ScrapedResult"]

Result i am getting in the datagridview is something like this only:
[image]

So what can i do other than that someone help me out with it?
JSON is:

```
    {
"category": "5428_5593752_8341994",
"brand": "Patio",
"format": "json",
"nextPage": "/v1/paginated/items?category=5428_5593752_8341994&brand=Patio&maxId=999930884&apiKey=z8w2s244z3y4c6845uwqzc98",
"totalPages": "1",
"items": [{
    "itemId": 19345483,
    "parentItemId": 19345483,
    "name": "Tahti Outdoor Patio Table Umbrella Lamp",
    "msrp": 300.0,
    "salePrice": 172.2,
    "upc": "833353177774",
    "categoryPath": "Patio & Garden/Outdoor Shade/Patio Umbrellas/Patio Umbrella Accessories",
    "shortDescription": "Add light instead of shade to your patio table with the Thati Outdoor Patio Table Umbrella Lamp. This unique lamp accommodates most standard patio tables with an umbrella hole up to 3-inches. If your table sits in a spot where an umbrella isn't necessary, this is a unique and charming alternative. Constructed of weatherproof materials, starting with the all resin base in a dark bronze finish, this lamp is made for the outdoors. The shade is all-weather, hand-woven PVC wicker and is available in your choice of Walnut or Antique Honey. An unbreakable polycarbonate light bulb enclosure protects the standard 100 watt bulb (not included) from any damage. Some simple assembly is required. Patio Living Concepts Incorporating aesthetics, function, and quality from the initial design phase to the finished product, Patio Living Concepts excels in creative product design",
    "longDescription": ". Their design and engineering team balance these parameters with reliability, safety and durability in mind. They craft an unsurpassed level of quality into every product, and meticulous quality inspections ensure conformity of all components. Patio Living Concepts strives to offer the finest quality leisure and lighting products at prices that are globally competitive. They are backed by over 38 years of experience in product design and engineering in the lighting industry.",
    "brandName": "Patio Living Concepts",
    "thumbnailImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/9ec4395d-be65-4636-b2ff-bce3df981f89_1.338332362d3de003ae37765ae406b543.jpeg?odnHeight=100&odnWidth=100&odnBg=ffffff",
    "mediumImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/9ec4395d-be65-4636-b2ff-bce3df981f89_1.338332362d3de003ae37765ae406b543.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff",
    "largeImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/9ec4395d-be65-4636-b2ff-bce3df981f89_1.338332362d3de003ae37765ae406b543.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=ffffff",
    "productTrackingUrl": "http://linksynergy.walmart.com/fs-bin/click?id=|LSNID|&offerid=223073.7200&type=14&catid=8&subid=0&hid=7200&tmpid=1082&RD_PARM1=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.walmart.com%252Fip%252FTahti-Outdoor-Patio-Table-Umbrella-Lamp%252F19345483%253Faffp1%253DI_INcA8xpLiW736-BdxAlFeIaiqJmqmv0YtBPcyaPsk%2526affilsrc%253Dapi",
    "standardShipRate": 0.0,
    "twoThreeDayShippingRate": 170.0,
    "color": "Brown",
    "marketplace": true,
    "modelNumber": "17777",
    "sellerInfo": "Vir Ventures Inc.",
    "productUrl": "http://c.affil.walmart.com/t/api01?l=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.walmart.com%2Fip%2FTahti-Outdoor-Patio-Table-Umbrella-Lamp%2F19345483%3Faffp1%3DI_INcA8xpLiW736-BdxAlFeIaiqJmqmv0YtBPcyaPsk%26affilsrc%3Dapi%26veh%3Daff%26wmlspartner%3Dreadonlyapi",
    "customerRating": "5.0",
    "numReviews": 3,
    "customerRatingImage": "http://i2.walmartimages.com/i/CustRating/5.gif",
    "categoryNode": "5428_5593752_8341994",
    "rhid": "35360",
    "bundle": false,
    "clearance": false,
    "preOrder": false,
    "stock": "Not available",
    "attributes": {
        "color": "Brown",
        "finerCateg": "Patio Umbrella Accessories",
        "mainimageurl": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/9ec4395d-be65-4636-b2ff-bce3df981f89_1.338332362d3de003ae37765ae406b543.jpeg"
    },
    "addToCartUrl": "http://c.affil.walmart.com/t/api01?l=http%3A%2F%2Faffil.walmart.com%2Fcart%2FaddToCart%3Fitems%3D19345483%7C1%26affp1%3DI_INcA8xpLiW736-BdxAlFeIaiqJmqmv0YtBPcyaPsk%26affilsrc%3Dapi%26veh%3Daff%26wmlspartner%3Dreadonlyapi",
    "affiliateAddToCartUrl": "http://linksynergy.walmart.com/fs-bin/click?id=|LSNID|&offerid=223073.7200&type=14&catid=8&subid=0&hid=7200&tmpid=1082&RD_PARM1=http%253A%252F%252Faffil.walmart.com%252Fcart%252FaddToCart%253Fitems%253D19345483%257C1%2526affp1%253DI_INcA8xpLiW736-BdxAlFeIaiqJmqmv0YtBPcyaPsk%2526affilsrc%253Dapi",
    "freeShippingOver35Dollars": false,
    "availableOnline": false
}, {
    "itemId": 19393431,
    "parentItemId": 19345483,
    "name": "Tahti Outdoor Patio Table Umbrella Lamp",
    "msrp": 248.92,
    "salePrice": 202.99,
    "categoryPath": "Patio & Garden/Outdoor Shade/Patio Umbrellas/Patio Umbrella Accessories",
    "shortDescription": "Add light instead of shade to your patio table with the Thati Outdoor Patio Table Umbrella Lamp. This unique lamp accommodates most standard patio tables with an umbrella hole up to 3-inches. If your table sits in a spot where an umbrella isn't necessary, this is a unique and charming alternative. Constructed of weatherproof materials, starting with the all resin base in a dark bronze finish, this lamp is made for the outdoors. The shade is all-weather, hand-woven PVC wicker and is available in your choice of Walnut or Antique Honey. An unbreakable polycarbonate light bulb enclosure protects the standard 100 watt bulb (not included) from any damage. Some simple assembly is required. Patio Living Concepts Incorporating aesthetics, function, and quality from the initial design phase to the finished product, Patio Living Concepts excels in creative product design",
    "longDescription": ". Their design and engineering team balance these parameters with reliability, safety and durability in mind. They craft an unsurpassed level of quality into every product, and meticulous quality inspections ensure conformity of all components. Patio Living Concepts strives to offer the finest quality leisure and lighting products at prices that are globally competitive. They are backed by over 38 years of experience in product design and engineering in the lighting industry.",
    "brandName": "Patio Living Concepts",
    "thumbnailImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/a245fff9-a843-498c-aa82-0b8554fd2059_1.23272356af2c7776abdd545d75739a7b.jpeg?odnHeight=100&odnWidth=100&odnBg=ffffff",
    "mediumImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/a245fff9-a843-498c-aa82-0b8554fd2059_1.23272356af2c7776abdd545d75739a7b.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff",
    "largeImage": "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/a245fff9-a843-498c-aa82-0b8554fd2059_1.23272356af2c7776abdd545d75739a7b.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=ffffff",
    "productTrackingUrl": "http://linksynergy.walmart.com/fs-bin/click?id=|LSNID|&offerid=223073.7200&type=14&catid=8&subid=0&hid=7200&tmpid=1082&RD_PARM1=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.walmart.com%252Fip%252FTahti-Outdoor-Patio-Table-Umbrella-Lamp%252F19393431%253Faffp1%253DI_INcA8xpLiW736-BdxAlFeIaiqJmqmv0YtBPcyaPsk%2526affilsrc%253Dapi",
    "standardShipRate": 0.0,
    "twoThreeDayShippingRate": 110.0,
    "color": "Yellow",
    "marketplace": true,
    "sellerInfo": "PlumStruck",
    "productUrl": "http://c.affil.walmart.com/t/api01?l=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.walmart.com%2Fip%2FTahti-Outdoor-Patio-Table-Umbrella-Lamp%2F19393431%3Faffp1%3DI_INcA8xpLiW736-BdxAlFeIaiqJmqmv0YtBPcyaPsk%26affilsrc%3Dapi%26veh%3Daff%26wmlspartner%3Dreadonlyapi",
    "categoryNode": "5428_5593752_8341994",
    "rhid": "35360",
    "bundle": false,
    "clearance": false,
    "stock": "Not available",
    "attributes": {
        "color": "Yellow",
        "productTaxCode": "2038345",
        "productUrlText": "/ip/Tahti-Outdoor-Patio-Table-Umbrella-Lamp/19393431"
    },
    "addToCartUrl": "http://c.affil.walmart.com/t/api01?l=http%3A%2F%2Faffil.walmart.com%2Fcart%2FaddToCart%3Fitems%3D19393431%7C1%26affp1%3DI_INcA8xpLiW736-BdxAlFeIaiqJmqmv0YtBPcyaPsk%26affilsrc%3Dapi%26veh%3Daff%26wmlspartner%3Dreadonlyapi",
    "affiliateAddToCartUrl": "http://linksynergy.walmart.com/fs-bin/click?id=|LSNID|&offerid=223073.7200&type=14&catid=8&subid=0&hid=7200&tmpid=1082&RD_PARM1=http%253A%252F%252Faffil.walmart.com%252Fcart%252FaddToCart%253Fitems%253D19393431%257C1%2526affp1%253DI_INcA8xpLiW736-BdxAlFeIaiqJmqmv0YtBPcyaPsk%2526affilsrc%253Dapi",
    "freeShippingOver35Dollars": false,
    "availableOnline": false
}]
}
```

Comment: Question level 0: does the `stores` variable contain the data after calling `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`? Question level 1: what about `dataGridViewScrapedData.DataSource = stores.items;`? But beware: the API returns a paginated result. That could be an issue for you to resolve. Maybe you can fetch all at once, but that could be too mutch also.

Comment: Answer level 0: **stores** have `count = 0`after calling `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

Comment: Answer level 1: `dataGridViewScrapedData.DataSource = stores.items` didn't work.

Comment: From the posted code… I am not sure what you would expect. The line `List<RootObject> stores = new List<RootObject>();` … creates an new “empty” list of `RootObjects.` …. Then the line… `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(ScrapedResult);` … appears to do nothing since this line “should” return a deserialized `RootObject` but it is not getting assigned to anything. In addition, It is unknown what `ScrapedResult` is. And lastly the setting of the `DataSource` to the grid…. `dataGridViewScrapedData.DataSource = stores;` appears correct since `stores` is an “empty” list.

Comment: @JohnG can u tell me how it could be done?

Comment: @blu. Do you want to list the items in your GridView?

Comment: yes @Mahdi can u help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need to populate the `DataSource` with a list of objects. There is only one list in your JSON string: `List<Item>`. Now you can use this list as a data source for your `GridView` like this:

```
var path = @"C:\MyStuff\json.txt";
var json = File.ReadAllText(path);
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
var items = rootObject.items;
MyGridView.DataSource = items;
// MyGridView.DataBind();
```

The only thing remaining is to show the first couple of properties namely, `category`, `brand`, `format`, `nextPage`, and `totalPages`. According to your JSON these seem to be fixed and if so, you can just show them outside the `GridView`.